# Create a "null" promise which resolves immediately

Tags: swift, promisekit

Is there a short way to do this...

```
Promise { fulfill, reject in fulfill(t) }
```

... where t is a T and the type of the promise is `Promise<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Promise(value: t)
```

where t is an instance of T